# Output of cut, value: command not found

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script
.

```
...
join -1 3 -2 3 $fileName1 $fileName2 > temp.txt
($(cut -d' ' -f1 temp.txt))
.    
.
```

I expect the output to be

```
c
```

but I get

```
c: command not found
```

I am really new to bash scripting, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I would suggest you get a nice book say, a shell scripting bible like [\[ this \]](http://as.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-111898384X.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 temp.text
```

When you put a command in `$()`, it substitutes the output back into the command line. And then, since this is at the beginning of the command line, it tries to execute the output as if it's another shell command.

Answer (score 2):

You are running `cut` command once within `$()` and then trying to execute the output of `cut` (in your case `c` i supppose) by putting another set of `()`.

So either run `cut` command alone if you want the output to be printed on stdout

```
cut -d' ' -f1 temp.text
```

or if you want to get the output in variable

```
var=$(cut -d' ' -f1 temp.text)
echo $var
```

Reference: [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) (Thanks @sjsam)

Comment: ^ but you might want to give a link that explains [\[ command substitution \]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)